# Find the units and zero divisors of $\mathbb Z_3 \oplus\mathbb Z_{6}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find the units and zero divisors of $\mathbb Z_3 \oplus\mathbb Z_{6}$.

I would think that the units are {1,1}, {1,5}, {2,1}, {2,5}

But are there any zero divisors, because 3 is prime.

Comment: By unitary, do you mean unit? Usually, elements in that ring will be noted by $(x,y)$ rather than $\{x,y\}$. Finally, $3$ being prime does not prevent the ring from having zero-divisors (this is not just $\mathbb{Z}_3$ after all).

Comment: Consider elements $(0,i)$.

Comment: Tobias, yes my textbook uses the tems unit as well as unitary. I thought zero cannot be a zero divider. Isn't (0,0) the same as zero?

Comment: Yes, $(0,0)$ is the $0$-element. But what about elements of the form $(0,y)$ for $y\neq 0$?

Comment: Primality is not completely relevant, $(1,0)(0,1)=(0,0)$. Anyway, $6$ is not prime.

Comment: Does this mean that in any group or ring there can be only one zero element?

Comment: Yes, this is a standard exercise (if there were two, try to add them and see that their sum would equal both of them, so they were actually equal).

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $R_1, R_2$ be rings then $U(R_1\times R_2)\cong U(R_1)\times U(R_2)$ where $U(R)$ denotes the group of units of the ring $R$.

By this, the ring $\mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_6$ has $2\times 2=4$ units. In a finite ring a nonzero element is either a zero divisor or a unit. So the ring has $18-4=14$ zero divisors.

Comment: You are right. I missed that part. Thanks for the update

Comment: I apologize for my mistake. would you mind by editing my answer whatever is necessary ?